# Upload a large Excel file and process asynchronously

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, asynchronous

I want to upload a large file of tracking numbers and process them into our ordering system.

I used to use

```
 Server.ScriptTimeout = 3000
```

It worked until we upgraded our servers and now it crashes.

I'm Getting

```
 This webpage is not available
 The connection to www.YourSite.com was interrupted.
```

I could see the .csv file has been uploaded, but many tracking numbers do not get processed.

I'm thinking of maybe switching to a asynchronous update. But I cannot find any good source for it.

If you have any good ideas, please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How big is the file??  It may be because of the file size limitation in the machine.config.  Try adding this to your web.config

```
<location path="Upload">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3000" maxRequestLength="20000" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Also, I don't recommend changing the value in the machine.config.  Better to have a single entry for large uploads rather than opening up every page to large uploads to help reduce DOS attacks.

To process the file asynchronously, have a look at using a BackgroundWorker.

http://gugiaji.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/backgroundworker-intro-part-1-work-with-progressbar/

Comment: Thank you Chris. It looks like we have a bigger issue on the server and it crashes at certain points. I have a copy of the site locally and it works but on the server it crashes. Where do i start?

Comment: I'd start my looking at the IIS logs and System logs.  There should be something in there indicating what failed.  After that, try inserting some debug code that outputs to local file.

Comment: Here is the new question, please let me know if you can help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213343/asp-net-pages-crash-in-iis-7-5-server-2008-but-worked-in-iis6-server-2003#comment14724813_11213343