# ASP.net pages crash in IIS 7.5/Server 2008 but worked in IIS6/Server 2003

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

We recently upgraded our server From windows 2003 to Windows 2008 and from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008. The site in general works, but some pages keep on crashing. it seems like the pages who take a bit longer than the usual crash.

I get this

```
This webpage is not available
The connection to www.YourSite.com was interrupted.
```

I have a carbon copy of the site on my local machine and everything works perfect.

Where do I start?

Managed Pipeline Mode is set to Classic. Should I change it to Integrated? (My local machine has it set to integrated).

Event Viewer
This happens every few minutes

Warning From WAS

```
A process serving application pool '186_NewSite' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '3832'. The data field contains the error number.
```

Application Error

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bd0eb
Faulting module name: mscorwks.dll, version: 2.0.50727.4961, time stamp: 0x4d8c149e
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000006c2689
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
```

.Net Runtime Error

```
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.4961 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (000007FEF8BD249A) (80131506)
```

This also happens quite often
MSSQLSERVER Error

```
The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 52, which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 29. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
```

Comment: We need more details to help you out.  Have you looked at the Event Viewer yet?

Comment: You "upgraded your server"?  From what to what?

Comment: Does the upgraded server have AVG antivirus with the email component? From experience, that component is prone to interrupting traffic from IIS. You could install WireShark on your local computer to see if you are receiving any reply from the server.

Comment: mscorwks.dll is core .NET dll. Maybe .NET FW installation is corrupted?

Comment: You might check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/4367865/425809.  Similar error.

Comment: Andrew, We don not have AVG Antivirus on the server.

Comment: @monsey11 Are you *sure* that you have explicitly called .Close on every connection you .Open to SQL Server?

Comment: @Andrew, the code runs fine on my local machine.

Comment: Tomas, How would I go about fixing a corrupted installation?

Comment: @monsey11 First, I would investigate the WAS errors: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735151%28v=ws.10%29 . Also, just because SQL Server works ok on the low load of your local machine without being sure you have closed connections does not mean it will work under the higher pressure of a more active situation (more experience speaking ;).

Comment: Here is a very thorough explanation of breaking changes in IIS7.x:  [http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/381/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis/](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/381/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis/)